# ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) вызывает ошибку: ImportError: cannot import name _imagingtk

Tags: python, tkinter, pil, изображения

Мне необходимо открыть изображения (png, jpg) в программе на Python + Tkinter. PIL, вроде бы, установлен правильно (использовал Pillow).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

image = Image.open('/home/1.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Однако возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 10, in <module>
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 123, in __init__
    except:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 188, in paste
    raise # configuration problem; cannot attach to Tkinter
ImportError: cannot import name _imagingtk
```

В чём может быть проблема? Сам _imagingtk импортируется нормально (имею в виду "import _imagingtk"), но это проблему не решает.

P. S. Если есть более простой способ открыть изображение в окне Tkinter - реквестирую его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Справился с проблемой. Ради интереса заглянул в `PIL/ImageTk.py`. А там была строчка `from PIL import _imagingtk`. Заменил её на `import _imagingtk`, переустановил `Pillow`, и всё заработало.

Появился другой вопрос: почему `Image` из `Tkinter` "перекрывает" `Image` из `PIL`? Т.е. если сначала импортировать PIL, а потом Tkinter, то выскочит `AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'open'`, а если `PIL` импортировать после `Tkinter`, то такого уже не будет.

Comment: Смотреть надо. Кстати, вот с правками Ваш текст:

    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import Tkinter

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    image = Image.open('a.png')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = Tkinter.Label(root, image=photo, bd=2, relief=Tkinter.SUNKEN)
    label.pack()

    root.mainloop()

(утопил для наглядности). Вообще Tkinter некоторые файлы сам может открывать (Tkinter.PhotoImage), но с Label что-то не получилось.

А проблемы с коллизиями имён возникают часто в разных языках, способ -- квалифицированные имена, напр Tkinter.Tk.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно также и я делал.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
windowMain = Tk()
windowMain.geometry('600x600+50+50')
im ='Директория\фото'
ph_im =PhotoImage(file=im)
canv111 = Canvas(windowMain, width=500, height=300)
canv111.create_image(1,1,anchor=NW,image=ph_im)
canv111.place(x=10,y=10)
windowMain.mainloop()
```